If a diffeomorphism has a dense orbit, are almost all of its orbits dense?
Let $M$ be a closed manifold. Suppose that a diffeomorphism $f:M\to M$ has a dense orbit. Is it true that almost every ofbit of $f$ is dense in $M$? Or, maybe, if the orbit of $x_0$ is dense, then all points sufficiently close to $x_0$ have dense orbits?
We may assume that $f$ is generic if needed.
Related question: is it important in this situation to consider $\{\ldots,f^{-2}(x_0),f^{-1}(x_0),x_0,f(x_0),f^2(x_0),\ldots\}$ as an orbit, or the assertion will be correct for $\{x_0,f(x_0),f^2(x_0),\ldots\}$ as well?

Almost all orbits are dense in the sense that a comeager dense set of points has a dense orbit, indeed if $(U_n){n\in\Bbb N}$ enumerates a countable basis of $M$, then the set of points with a dense orbit is $\bigcap_n G\cdot U_n$. For every $n$, $G\cdot U_n$ is dense (since there is a dense orbit), so that the intersection is dense by the Baire category theory (and it is comeager being $G\delta$)

Take any linear Anosov diffeomorphism $f: T^2\to T^2$. Then periodic points of $f$ are dense in $T^2$ (projection to $T^2$ of every point in $\mathbb Q^2\subset \mathbb R^2$ is periodic). At the same time, due to ergodicity of $f$, almost every (semi)orbit is dense in $T^2$. Hence, your guess about points "sufficiently close to points with dense orbits" is wrong. It is not hard to construct homeomorphisms of compact surfaces which have positive measure of the set of points with dense (semi)orbits and also a closed proper invariant subset of positive measure. I see no reason for this to be impossible for diffeomorphisms of compact manifolds. It used to be the case that Moscow was one of the best places in the world to study smooth dynamics and, hence, find local experts in questions you are asking. I guess, this is no longer the case. Sigh...
Edit. Indeed, already for 2-dimensional tori there are area-preserving diffeomorphisms with some dense orbits, such that the measure of the set of points with dense orbits equals zero. This is a consequence of Theorem 5.1 in
Fayad, Bassam; Katok, Anatole, Constructions in elliptic dynamics, Ergodic Theory Dyn. Syst. 24, No. 5, 1477-1520 (2004). ZBL1089.37012.
In fact, they prove existence of such diffeomorphisms for all compact connected manifolds of dimension $\ge 2$ which admit volume-preserving nontrivial circle actions.
